# AngularJS - trying to get background color to change with ng-switch and ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my first question - and it is really just more of a frustration. I've went through about 12 different stack overflow questions that are similar and have copied their code and I still can't get the bloody background color to change on click. So I assume I'm missing something.

https://codepen.io/Dawsraki/pen/XRGBLW

```
<html ng-app="app"> 
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="SwitchController" ng-style="myStyle">
  <div ng-switch="slider.page" class="screen" >
  <div  id="record_player" ng-switch-when="1">
    <span><a href="#"  ng-click="slider.page=1; myStyle={background:'#2a1f2d;'}">&#60;</a></span>
    <div class="rectangle">
      <div class="circle1">      
          <div class="circle3">
          </div>     
      </div>
      <div class="handle"> 
        <div class="circle1">
        </div>
        <div class="hand">
        </div>
        <div class="arm">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="toggles">
        <div class="left_dash"></div>
        <div class="right_dash"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Listen to Music</h1>
    <span><a href="#" ng-click="slider.page=2">&#62;</a></span>
  </div>
  <div id="cassette" ng-switch-when="2">
     <span><a href="#" ng-click="slider.page=1; myStyle={background:'#5F78D2'}">&#60;</a></span>
    <div class="rectangle">
      <div class="circle1">
      </div>
      <div class="line1">
      </div>
      <div class="line2">
      </div>
      <div class="line3">
      </div>
      <div class="line4">
      </div>     
      <div class="circle2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Share it with friends</h1>
    <span><a href="#" ng-click="slider.page=1">&#62;</a></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code pen - I want the background color to change when I click on the arrow and I have seen so many simple solutions but they just arn't working and I've no idea why. If anyone wants to help an AngularJS noob out there will be much love and biscuits <3 (DISCLAIMER: biscuits will not be provided)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to ng-switch, as it creates its own scope.

Use $parent.myStyle={background:'red'}" in your anchor tag to fix this